# Как перемножить элементы массива?

Tags: c#, массивы

Допустим, есть `int` массив с 9 элементами, которые надо перемножить для вычисления контрольной суммы по ниже описанному алгоритму:

```
Указан СНИЛС 112-233-445 95
Проверяем правильность контрольного числа:
цифры номера        1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5
номер позиции       9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Сумма = 1×9 + 1×8 + 2×7 + 2×6 + 3×5 + 3×4 + 4×3 + 4×2 + 5×1 = 95
95 ÷ 101 = 0, остаток 95.
Контрольное число 95 — указано верно
```

Как это аккуратно сделать? Ниже код:

```
Console.Write("snils_crc>"); str_snls = Console.ReadLine();

//Генерируем исключение для проверки воодимх данных.
try
{
    str_snls_num = Convert.ToInt32(str_snls);

    char[] chr_snls = str_snls.ToCharArray();
    int[] int_snls = new int[chr_snls.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < chr_snls.Length; i++)
    {
        int_snls[i] = int.Parse(chr_snls[i].ToString());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < int_snls.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(int_snls[i].ToString());
    }
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```

Тут пользователь вводит цифры, которые конвертируются в `char[]`, а потом в `int[]` массив. Во втором цикле просто выводятся посимвольно. Помогите составить корректный цикл.

Comment: VladD, ошибки:

    Ошибка 1 Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "string.Split(params char[])" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов

Ошибка 2 Аргумент "1": преобразование типа из "string" в "char[]" невозможно

Для: 

    string.Split(Console.ReadLine())

Comment: @VladD Я не могу почему-то комментировать дальше. Код:

    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace snsl_cr
    {
        class Program
        {
             static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var numbers = string.Split(Console.ReadLine()).Select(int.Parse).ToList();
                var positions = string.Split(Console.ReadLine()).Select(int.Parse).ToList();
                var crc = numbers.Zip(positions, (x, y) => x * y).Sum() % 101;
            }
        }
    

Comment: @sys1n4: Да, вы правы, я ошибся в синтаксисе. Подправил ответ. Правильно не `string.Split(Console.ReadLine())`, а `Console.ReadLine().Split()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держите:

```
var numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToList();
var positions = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToList();
var crc = numbers.Zip(positions, (x, y) => x * y).Sum() % 101;
```

Циклы не нужны, оставьте их в прошлом тысячелетии.

---

Ага, у вас другой формат ввода. Не проблема.

```
var input = "112-233-445 95";
var split = input.Split();
var digits = split[0].Where(char.IsDigit).Select(c => c - '0').Reverse();
var computedCrc = digits.Select((d, index) => d * (index + 1)).Sum() % 101;
var crc = int.Parse(split[1]);
```

Comment: >Циклы не нужны, оставьте их в прошлом тысячелетии

минуточка бубнежа и брюзжания: циклы стоит оставлять в прошлом веке только при условии хорошего понимания того, что такое IEnumerable, IEnumerator, итератор и лямбда-функция. А если еще юзается что-то вроде EntityFramework, то еще и что такое IQueryable и отложенное выполнение. Иначе в погоне за лаконичностью кода можно "забыть" изучить базовые понятия. 

Ну а вообще, да - лямбды - это здорово)

Comment: @DreamChild: ну, без этого никуда. Только это не брюзжание, а суровая необходимость. Я сейчас вот ещё Rx extensions пытаюсь осилить, это как LINQ в квадрате.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как работает этот код...

    string.Split(Console.ReadLine())

Не принимает Console.ReadLine(). Уже сконвертированный мной массив char[] chr_snls = тоже не принимает.

Comment: Что значит «не принимает»? Не компилируется?

Comment: Ошибка 1 Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "string.Split(params char[])" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов

Ошибка 2 Аргумент "1": преобразование типа из "string" в "char[]" невозможно

Comment: Не тот формат))

    var input = "11223344595"; //Лучше так

Ввод должен быть без тире и пробелов. Такой ввод трудно проверить)

Comment: И еще хотелось бы ссылку на хорошие, годные маны по IEnumerable, IEnumerator, итераторе и лямбда-функции)) Что бы понять как это работает)

Comment: @sys1n4: у меня всё компилируется. Выложите ваш код и сообщение об ошибке, хорошо?

Comment: Вызовы `ToList()` в первом примере не обязательны, зачем материализировать запросы лишний раз?

Comment: @Олег Нечитайло: Потому что я хочу гарантировать, что `Console.ReadLine` выполнится тогда, когда я хочу, а не потом.

Представьте себе такой код, например:

    Console.Write("Введите числа: ");
    var numbers = string.Split(Console.ReadLine()).Select(int.Parse);
    Console.Write("Введите позиции: ");
    var positions = string.Split(Console.ReadLine()).Select(int.Parse);

Если у строчек с `var` ленивая семантика, `Console.ReadLine()` потенциально может выполниться когда угодно. Поэтому я в явном виде требую энергичную семантику, не полагаясь на стечение обстоятельств.

Comment: посмотрите IL код и убедитесь, что ReadLine вызовется когда надо. 

сначала будет вызвано ReadLine, после чего вызвано Split, после чего результат Split будет передан в ф-ию Select, которая вернет ленивый Enumerable

Comment: @Олег Нечитайло: я знаю, что `string.Split` энергичный. Но для того чтобы это понять, надо потратить усилия, и здесь легко допустить ошибку: в одном выражении сцеплены функции с как ленивой, так и энергичной семантикой, а это — потенциальный источник ошибок. Давайте подойдём к коду на более высоком уровне. Формально правильный код без `ToList` будет тем не менее _хрупким_: небольшое изменение сделает его неправильным.

Comment: @Олег Нечитайло:  Если вы хотите не тратить ресурсы на материализацию, _необходимо_ отделить ленивый код от энергичного явно:

    var numberStrings = string.Split(Console.ReadLine()); // eager
    var numbers = numberStrings.Select(int.Parse);        // lazy

и т. д.

Поверьте, чистая семантика настолько же важна, как, например, объявление полей как `private` (хотя формально правильно было бы оставить их `public` и просто не менять снаружи.) по тем же самым причинам: это защищает от _непреднамеренных_ ошибок.